# How to calculate the difference between two rows

Tags: r

Basically I have a column in an R dataframe, and I want to find a code to compute the following function:

```
(i - (i-1)) - ((i+1) - i)
```

In other words, for the left side of the function I want to subtract the value from the previous row `(i-1)` from `i`, and for the right side of the function I want to subtract `i` from the value from the next row `(i+1)`

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can someone please benchmark? I have to leave.

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

```
x <- (1:5)^2
#[1]  1  4  9 16 25
as.vector(filter(x,c(-1,2,-1),sides=1))    
#[1] NA NA -2 -2 -2
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you are correct. However, what should be used depends on where you prefer your `NA` values or how you want to align with other columns in a data.frame.

Answer (score 8):

Or like this?
What should happen on the borders?

```
x <- (1:5)^2
-diff(diff(x))
# [1] -2 -2 -2
```

Comment: Good idea! +1 It can be simplified further: `-diff(x,1,2)`

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: Nice catch! It is simpler and in a benchmark slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your description is not clear. If `a` is a vector, what you are asking would be provided by:

```
f <- diff(a[-length(a)]) - diff(a[-1])
```

and would be defined for 1 < i < length(a), thus length(f) = length(a) - 2

Replace a with your data.frame column.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar scenarios before. Ideally you should stick to vectorised code, as it's much faster. What I have done is make two new vectors, one shifting everything up one (i-1) or shifting down one (i+1), then using these in a calculation:

```
i <- (1:5)^2

i.next     <- c(i[2:length(i)],NA)
i.previous <- c(NA,i[1:length(i)-1])

i.calculation <- (i - i.previous) - (i.next - i)

cbind(i,i.next,i.previous,i.calculation)

# i i.next i.previous i.calculation
# [1,]  1      4         NA            NA
# [2,]  4      9          1            -2
# [3,]  9     16          4            -2
# [4,] 16     25          9            -2
# [5,] 25     NA         16            NA
```

Comment: The problem with my solution (apart from the fact that it's rather long winded!) is that it doesn't give sensible answers for the data point 1 or N, which should both be undefined (NA).

Comment: I fixed this now by adding 'NA' values for the first and final one.